# Unexpected behaviour of Access-Control-Allow-Origin when tested locally

Tags: docker, nginx, cors, html5-video, response-headers

I'm running an NGINX web server locally and I don't understand why, despite the presence of `access-control-allow-origin: www.site-A.test` in the response, a page of origin `www.site-B.test` is still allowed to load resources from origin `www.site-A.test`.

I expected that video file at `www.site-A.test` not to play anywhere other than `www.site-A.test`. That is not the behaviour I observe locally.

Both sites are locally running on macOS on NGINX 1.21.4 and in Docker environment. Tested in Firefox Developer Edition 95.

---

REPRODUCTION OF EXAMPLE
(actual hosts that I'm testing at)

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
    map $sent_http_content_type $cors {
        ~*video/ $scheme://$server_name;
    }
    # There are two more blocks that handle redirection to this server block
    server {
       listen 8443 ssl http2;
       listen [::]:8443 ssl http2;
       server_name www.nginx.test;

       # Access-Control-Allow-Origin
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
    }
    # There are two more blocks that handle redirection to this server block
    server {
       listen 8443 ssl http2;
       listen [::]:8443 ssl http2;
       server_name www.nginx1.test;

       # Access-Control-Allow-Origin
       add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors always;
    }
}
```

Port `8334` is container's port. Both websites listen on `443` port.
In this scenario every `content-type: video/mp4` is shareable only within host that a resource is coming from.

**[www.nginx1.test](http://www.nginx1.test)**

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
             <source src="https://www.nginx.test/SampleVideo_1280x720_5mb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshot of GET and Response Headers** at *www.nginx1.test*
[image]

Comment: Can you please use actual origins values? Because `www.site-A.test` and `www.site-B.test` are _not_ origins. Also, please add some minimal reproducible example; it's not clear to me what you're referring to by "_I expected that video file at www.site-A.test wont't be able played_".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're observing is expected behaviour. The premise of your question is incorrect: you *can* embed a video in your page using the `<video>` HTML element without needing the server to specifically allow your origin. See [MDN's page about the Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#cross-origin_network_access):

> Here are some examples of resources which may be embedded cross-origin:
>
> - [...]
> - Media played by `<video>` and `<audio>`.

Cases where you do [need the resource to be CORS-enabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image) are limited to when you want to [use the video within a `<canvas>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-crossorigin).

If you want to prevent third-party sites from embedding a video, you can implement some [resource isolation policy](https://web.dev/fetch-metadata/) on the server side.

Comment: Hmm I see. But why it's intended to work like this it's perhaps for another reading. Anyway why to go all this way if it doesn't accomplish the idea? I think I can too block sharing resources using NGINX's variable `$invalid_referer` in `location` directive.

Comment: @DominikKrulak The SOP was never intended to prevent people from embedding videos on their page. Same with images. Imagine a world where you cannot embed images served by a different origin; that would be quite restrictive.